# iphone - Thread is not stopped, why it run on my program background.?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsthread

I have a thread in my program. It run by NSTimer. when i stop my NSThread or NSTimer. It stops my Thread. But when again i want to run the thread in my program it show me that, the previous thread is not stop. So previous thread and current thread are run together. My program is given below.

```
- (void) startTimer{
    timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] 
                             initWithTarget:self 
                             selector:@selector(startTimerThread) object:nil];

    [timerThread start];
}

-(void) startTimerThread{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                      target: self
                                    selector: @selector(timerTick:)
                                    userInfo: nil
                                     repeats: YES] retain];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)stopTimer{

    [timer invalidate];
    [timer release];
    timer = nil;
}

- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"THik");
}
```

I my program there is two button one for starting the thread another is for stop the thread. For the first time to run and stop the thread it works properly. but second time(After stop the thread) when i again want to run the thread it show me that, The previous thread is not stop and two thread is run simultaneously. Please help me.

How can i stop a thread and when i want to run the thread again it run a new thread not with the previous one.

Comment: Hey here you are stopping the timer not the thread. and as far as threads are concern you can run multiple of threads regardless of their method body. i.e. you can have multiple threads for `startTimerThread`

Comment: and what you want actually create new thread or just run the previous one.?

Answer (score 1):

You are only stopping the timer in the stopTimer method. The thread is still executing.
To stop a thread, you can do `[NSThread exit];`

This will stop the "current" thread.

To learn more on stopping threads, refer its class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and check out the "exit" method.

So if on main thread you call `[NSThread exit]`, it will exit the main thread.